# SSL certificate identity issue in Evolution Mail

Tags: linux, email, ssl, certificate, evolution

I'm experiencing a problem with a SSL certificate inside Evolution Mail.

When I open the program, I receive the following warning:

> The certificate does not match the expected identity of the site that
>   it was retrieved from.

To be more precise, here is what the dialog looks like

[image]

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the name used to access the mail server(ie pop, imap snd/or smtp server) is not the same as the name imbedded in the certificate - the solution is to either contact your mail provider and get the appropriate name, or.find the correct name in the cert. (The Subject name or Subject Alt name Field)